# [R]: Bootstrap confidence interval of loess fit does not match default CI of ggplot. Why?

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval, loess

I tried to construct a confidence interval of a loess fit using a manually created bootstrap. However the confidence interval I got, was much more narrow than the one ggplot returns by default. Anyone knows the reason for the mismatch?

Here is my data.frame:

```
  structure(list(year = c(2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), week = c(23L, 24L, 26L, 
28L, 29L, 31L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 17L, 
20L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 39L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 
21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 
19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 16L, 18L, 
20L, 22L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 40L, 42L, 44L, 
13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 
39L, 41L, 43L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 
31L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 43L), reserves.mean_diff = c(10.1021084736772, 
-0.766463989038282, -13.3480825958702, 17.8524842879165, -3.65951527473115, 
1.25720024253449, -2.44358947696786, -17.1734197730956, -15.2733472665273, 
23.9757799671593, -6.90926973198919, 12.8512968646567, 33.8026439651291, 
18.8290534923951, -6.75273931878027, -9.05567300916137, 0.840392801449825, 
13.2816315367936, 23.5379000084883, 114.685222001325, 198.219131614654, 
45.9449929478138, 40.6682593034992, 36.5758841997304, -5.12350207874786, 
2.99091939616023, 9.20093249342791, 13.8286436077293, 3.33161344050982, 
2.74206598939135, 4.69395418700713, 37.0653947533576, 32.8195752624717, 
15.1376101619812, 21.6067582543964, -12.6387803896504, -8.48222761312096, 
-10.7138207854198, -6.81756227706404, -0.54799470071059, 17.4370345102052, 
24.5750168199148, 42.3207905314873, 11.3309122402984, 14.3100926377377, 
20.5176126940119, -14.6109288289383, -9.20511061567485, 11.0733419545538, 
10.8024051420278, -0.270057655436401, -1.46335127110781, -5.14283957701451, 
-40.3864151315141, -10.050054938347, 4.99244875943903, -14.7405146096816, 
-1.8940167449459, 23.0718835304823, 3.97416790859413, -0.186360431147362, 
-29.3893983448893, -33.5619726446489, -5.45050664215525, -4.35281287605294, 
-8.66795740561471, 13.0625079675349, 17.3863495323096, -12.5987228607918, 
13.0244755244755, 40.8933424230256, 154.135831381733, 176.376963350785, 
126.405959031657, 9.35348446683459, -24.0794856808884, -35.2401205032784, 
-33.9074690157674, -22.7480817589787, -53.1701860642767, -39.5347211123542, 
-33.7617080905671, -23.2400740379139, -28.6645273028933, -39.172670230072, 
-29.6969696969697, 65.3609831029186, -5.3627760252366, -8.31635425156209, 
NA, -18.1931150293871, -63.7999305314345, -12.6303538175047, 
-35.0136818267598, -39.5103036251362, -33.7963505188447, -28.8472127068456, 
-14.4943657203656, -17.1046782114241, -12.0518976349798, -5.0786412899815
)), .Names = c("year", "week", "reserves.mean_diff"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(8L, 
233L, 458L, 683L, 908L, 1133L, 1358L, 1583L, 1808L, 2033L, 2258L, 
2483L, 2708L, 2933L, 3158L, 3383L, 3608L, 3833L, 4058L, 4283L, 
4508L, 4733L, 4958L, 5183L, 5408L, 5633L, 5858L, 6083L, 6308L, 
6533L, 6758L, 6983L, 7208L, 7433L, 7658L, 7883L, 8108L, 8333L, 
8558L, 8783L, 9008L, 9233L, 9458L, 9683L, 9908L, 10133L, 10358L, 
10583L, 10808L, 11033L, 11258L, 11483L, 11708L, 11933L, 12158L, 
12383L, 12608L, 12833L, 13058L, 13283L, 13508L, 13733L, 13958L, 
14183L, 14408L, 14633L, 14858L, 15083L, 15308L, 15533L, 15758L, 
15983L, 16208L, 16433L, 16658L, 16883L, 17108L, 17333L, 17558L, 
17783L, 18008L, 18233L, 18458L, 18683L, 18908L, 19133L, 19358L, 
19583L, 19808L, 20033L, 20258L, 20483L, 20708L, 20933L, 21158L, 
21383L, 21608L, 21833L, 22058L, 22283L, 22508L))
```

And here the script with which I tried to build a bootstrap:

```
boot.loess = function(df = my.df, R = 1000, 
                      y.var = "reserves.mean_diff", x.var = "week", x.values = weeks){
    all.bootstraps = data.frame()
    sample.size = nrow(df)
    repeat {
        df.sample = df[sample(nrow(df),sample.size, replace = T),]

        lo.fit <- loess(get(y.var) ~ get(x.var), data = df.sample, control=loess.control(surface="direct"))
        predicted.y = predict(lo.fit,x.values )
        one.bootstrap = as.data.frame(t(data.frame(predicted.y)))
        names(one.bootstrap) = x.values
        all.bootstraps = rbind(all.bootstraps, one.bootstrap)

        if(nrow(all.bootstraps)== R+1){
            break
        }
    }
    CI.all.weeks = data.frame()
    for(i in 1:length(x.values)){
        CI.lower_one.week = quantile(all.bootstraps[,i],0.025)
        CI.upper_one.week = quantile(all.bootstraps[,i],0.975)
        CI.one.week = data.frame(x.values[i],CI.lower_one.week,CI.upper_one.week)
        names(CI.one.week)= c("week","CI.lower","CI.upper")
        CI.all.weeks = rbind(CI.all.weeks,CI.one.week)
    }
return(CI.all.weeks)
}
CI.all.weeks <- boot.loess()
```

I plotted then the ggplot default CI (grey area) and the upper and lower boundaries of the bootstrapped CI (as points):

```
df.plot =  merge(my.df, CI.all.weeks)

ggplot(df.plot,aes(x = week, y = reserves.mean_diff)) + geom_smooth() +
    geom_point(aes(x = week, y = CI.lower))+ 
    geom_point(aes(x = week, y = CI.upper))
```

Unfortunately, my CI looks much to narrow as you can see: 
[image: Confidence intervals of loess, created by ggplot and by my bootstrap attempt]

Anyone knows the reason for this mismatch? What did I do wrong?

PS: In case you are wondering why I write this manually, although there are bootstrap functions available. I do this to create in a next step a CI for the first derivative of a loess fit. So when this works, I will differentiate numerically each fit and then take equally the 97.5% and 2.5% percentile to get the CI for the first derivative of the loess fit.

EDIT: I am using now the quantiles function as suggested by Roland. However I could not figure out how to use the boot function. This is what I tried:

```
loess.fit = function(data = df){
    lo.fit = loess(get(y.var) ~ get(x.var), data = data, control=loess.control(surface="direct"))
    predicted.y = predict(lo.fit,x.values)
    one.bootstrap = as.data.frame(t(data.frame(predicted.y)))
    return(one.bootstrap)
}
boot(data=df, statistic=loess.fit, R=R)
```

I also added the return command after aosmith noted that it was missing.

As aosmith pointed rightly out, my function was actually not used because I hadn't assigned it to anything. What a rookie mistake. I also placed the return function in a different position. Here you can see that it still does not match it very well but, it is much better and I guess acceptable.

[image: CI bootstrap]

Thanks @aosmith

Comment: There is no reason to use a `repeat` loop here. Use package boot instead. Then your code would be more readable (and efficient). You should also use `quantile` to get the CI from the bootstrap result.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I change now to the quantile function. I did not manage to get the boot function work. Does this function make the script only more readable and efficient or does it change the magnitude of the CI?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. If you add `return(CI.all.weeks)` to your function directly before the last closing brace the function will return the CI data.frame.  These CI seem reasonable, so my guess is you have an object named `CI.all.weeks` in your environment and were plotting with that instead of what `boot.loess` returned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Good point. However the plot did not change. (I think while I was building the function, I created the exact same object just not in a function)

Comment: After editing your function, did you assign the result to something before merging?  Like `all = boot.loess()`?  It is this last object that you'll want to merge with the original dataset for plotting.  Consider cleaning your environment, as well.  It is much easier to troubleshoot when you get useful errors when objects don't exist.

Comment: Thanks. :-) You were right with what you said. Looks much better now. I guess this is good enough. I think it is not surprising that different methods yield somehow different CIs. If you want you can put your troubleshooting advices in an answer and then I will accept it.